# Counting how many times an integer is equal to itself, then calculating the percentage

Tags: c, arrays, count, integer

I have an array and I have integers in the array. I'm trying to count the number of times the integers in the array repeat themselves. After that I want to print the percentage. This is what I have so far.

```
for(i = 2; i < 8; i++){
    mmblk[i] = (num[i] / bsize);   //mmblk[i] =0,0,1,9,0,1
    if(mmblk[i] == mmblk[i]){      
        count ++;
        p = count/num[0];
        percent = (p * 100);
    }
}
printf("Highest possible hit rate = %d/%d = %d %\n", count, num[0], percent);//num[0]=6
```

For the output I get:
Highest possible hit rate = 0/6 = 0

The output should look like:
Highest possible hit rate = 3/6 = 50 %

I know there is something way wrong going on but I can't figure out what it is. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is num[i]? why iterating from 2 to 8? what is the size of mmblk array?

Comment: `if(mmblk[i] == mmblk[i]){` oh my oh my oh my

Comment: @Jeeva num[i] is another array that has characters from lines that come from a text file. It starts at 2 and goes to 8 because those are the only lines I wanted to use from the file. mmblk has a size of 32.

Comment: @suddnely_me I figured that was wrong as I was typing it here, but I can't think of any other way to check it.

Comment: What are you trying to check? You need to check if it is equal to some number(say 0), of course its always going to equal itself....

Comment: @jzworkman I thought about that but I didn't know how to do it. It has 0,0,1,9,0,1 in it. After reading each number I guess it should store it and continue reading to see if it has a duplicate in the array and if it does count should increase. So after reading each number count should be 3 because 0 is repeated twice after the initial 0 and 1 is repeated once after the initial 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I understand correctly,  you are looking for the maximum number of repeated values in the array.

```
func( {1,2,3} ) = 0
func( {1,1,3} ) = 2
func( {1,1,1} ) = 3
```

To get the percentage, you simply divide this result by the length of the array.

The problem is your function is way too simple, and not really at all the solution.

The solution I'm coming up with on first approach, is to have another array called counts. This is the same length as your source array. It ends up being the number of times each number in the source array appears.

For each item in the source array, you count how many times that number appears, and store that result in counts. Then you find the maximum of the counts array, and you have a) the max repeats value you're looking for, and b) the index of the corresponding maximum-repeated-value from the source array.

For the example {0,0,1,9,0,1} :

```
src    counts
  0       3        Max 
  0       3
  1       2
  9       1
  0       3
  1       2
```

One optimization to this, is while you are counting, if you encounter the same number earlier in the array, you can stop, because you already have counted repeats for that value.

With that in place, your result is:

```
src    counts
  0       3        Max 
  0       0        
  1       2
  9       1
  0       0
  1       0
```

Another optimization is to only start counting from your current index in the array. This works for the same reason as the other optimization.

Results:

```
src    counts
  0       3        Max 
  0       2
  1       2
  9       1
  0       1
  1       1
```

Comment: so if the numbers in the source array change will this still work?

Comment: Yes why wouldn't it? I didn't give any code because I think you need to understand what it is you're trying to do, not just plop some code in and hope it works. That's how we end up with software like Windows.

Comment: lol. I was just checking. I didn't mention that the numbers would be changing earlier. I haven't written code since 2003. I have a question. If I don't know what the number is going to be that I'm trying to keep count of, how do I compare it?

Comment: You have two nested loops. The outer one is going through each element of the array. The inner loop takes the value at that index, and then goes through the whole array again, testing each element for equality against the current value. If they equal, you increment the count for that value. Then go on to the next element in the array.

Comment: I mean come on, you have all the values you want to test, just go through them all, and see how many of each of them there are. **Do it manually** on a piece of paper; the algorithm will come to you.

Comment: I understand what you are saying and yes that will work if I knew what the values in the source would be. In the rest of my code I ask the user to enter values, I take the input and do some calculatioins and store them to my source array. So checking for 0, 1, and 9 won't work when something else is entered.

Comment: If I understand your algorithm right, it has an O(n^2) complexity, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, I believe that is correct. The optimizations make it a little better, but I'm not sure if it is O(n*log(n)) or not... it might be.

Comment: @oldbutnew - I don't think you're understanding. You're not checking for 0, 1, and 9, you're checking for src[0], src[1], src[2]. It absolutely does not matter what the values are, the algorithm will work. What is the point of writing software that only works on certain values?

Answer (score 0):

if you have only small integers, you can use an array in which you count number of occurences of the integers

```
const int MAX_INT = 1024;
const int FIRST   = 2;
const int LAST    = 7;

unsigned int count[MAX_INT];
int i;

for (i = 0; i < MAX_INT; i++)
    count[i] = 0;

for (i = FIRST; i <= LAST; i++) {
    if (numbers[i] >= MAX_INT) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Too large number");
        exit 1;
    }
    count[numbers[i]] += 1;
}

for (i = 0; i < MAX_INT; i++)
    if (count[i] > 0)
        // print your statistics
```

If you have large integers occurring, so large that you cannot make your array `count` large enough you'll need something more sophisticated I guess; sorting your numbers first could be an option.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a linked list or some other variable-length container where each data node stores a number and how many times it occurs.

In pseudocode:

VariableLengthContainer v = EMPTY-CONTAINER
n = size(input)
for each number in the input
   if that number is in the container, increment its count
   otherwise, add that number to the container and set its count to 1